# expected an indented block at python list declaration

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a simple code in python but I receive this error can any one help

```
def toss(n=3):
res = []
for i in range(n):
    res.append(random.choice(['T','H']))
    return res
```

and I receive *`expected an indented block`* and points to *res*

Comment: Your function isn't indented.

Comment: `def ...:` announces a function definition. Everything inside the function definition should be indented.

Comment: aha, thanks I really did not know that , what a crazy compiler :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not indented properly. Should be

```
def toss(n=3):
    res = []
    for i in range(n):
        res.append(random.choice(['T','H']))
    return res
```

Comment: thanks for answer and also now face NameError: name 'toss' is not defined in pyshell can you help me with that too

Comment: @SaeidehValipour you have to run your function as toss(), or toss(number)

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong as you didn't indent your code. The correct syntax would be:

```
def toss(n=3):
    res = []
    for i in range(n):
        res.append(random.choice(['T','H']))
    return res
```

For more info, you could take a look at http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html